# Regular expression in bean shell preprocessor in jmeter

Tags: regex

Please help me to write the regular expression for the following in jmeter

> "connections":"1","objects":"one",

I need to get value `1`. I tried like this

```
"connections":"(.+?)"
```

This works fine when there is a value .

If there is no value after : i.e.,
`"connections":"",`
then reg.ex returns `",` (double quotes and comma)
which is creating problem.

I need a regex which accepts alphanumeric and at the same point of time excludes double quotes and comma if there is no value.

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `.` which default matches any character but newline.

> and at the same point of time excludes double quotes...

What're you probably after, is called a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
"connections":"([^"]+)"
```

`[^"]+` matches one or more characters, that are not `"`. If you know, that there can only be digits between the double quotes, use `\d+` instead of `[^"]+` for restricting to`[0-9]` only. If you know there can only be alphanumeric, use `[A-Za-z0-9]` or `[[:alnum:]]` if available.

[See the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uV1pB7/1)

Comment: It works for me. But I am getting problem when thereP is empty value within double quotes.  Regular expression needs to return the value in double quotes if any value is there. else it shdn't return any value.  Pl. help me to sort this issue. I tries many expressions but not getting.

Comment: @murthy [Check out the demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV1pB7/1). This regex does not match anything if there's nothing inside the double quotes. Please provide a sample for testing, where this regex fails. Do you mean if there is white-space only inside the double quotes, it should fail? If so, try `"connections":"\s*([^\s"][^"]*?)\s*"` [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC8qB6/1).